# Docker pihole Setup Stopping at lighttpd service

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am installing pihole in an ubuntu docker image. However, the setup stops and exists at "Restarting lighttpd service."

Here is my base.docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV term=xterm
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN \
    apt-get update --fix-missing\
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Pihole commands 
RUN mkdir /etc/pihole 
COPY pihole/setupVars.conf /etc/pihole
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get install -y dialog
RUN apt-get install -y dhcpcd5
RUN  apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt install git -y
RUn  apt-get install -y iproute2
RUN apt-get install -y whiptail
RUN apt-get install php-sqlite3 -y
RUN apt-get install bc
RUN apt-get --yes --no-install-recommends install netcat idn2 sqlite3 lighttpd php-common php-cgi php-sqlite3
RUN apt-get install dnsutils -y
RUN apt-get install iputils-ping -y
RUN apt-get install -y lsof
RUN apt-get install sudo -y
RUN apt-get install unzip -y
RUN apt-get install -y dns-root-data

RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections 
RUN echo "resolvconf resolvconf/linkify-resolvconf boolean false" | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt install resolvconf -y

#RUN apt-get -y install tzdata
#RUN dpkg --configure -a
#RUN apt-get install -f
#RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#RUN apt-get remove --purge resolvconf
#RUN apt-get --yes --no-install-recommends install resolvconf php-cgi php-sqlite3

RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN sed -r -i.orig 's/#?DNSStubListener=yes/DNSStubListener=no/g' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
RUN curl -L https://install.pi-hole.net | bash /dev/stdin --unattended
```

I am copying the necessary parameters required for pihole setup from setupVars.conf. the file is as below:

```
PIHOLE_INTERFACE=Enter data here
IPV4_ADDRESS=Enter data here
IPV6_ADDRESS=
PIHOLE_DNS_1=8.8.8.8
PIHOLE_DNS_2=8.8.4.4
QUERY_LOGGING=true
INSTALL_WEB_SERVER=true
INSTALL_WEB_INTERFACE=true
LIGHTTPD_ENABLED=true
WEBPASSWORD=Enter password here
BLOCKING_ENABLED=true
```

However, the setup stops at "Restarting lightpd service", below is what the terminal looks like:

```
Step 23/51 : RUN apt-get install -y whiptail
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d2b7797e4e88
Step 24/51 : RUN apt-get install php-sqlite3 -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 17743bc99367
Step 25/51 : RUN apt-get install bc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fc220b2ce2d3
Step 26/51 : RUN apt-get --yes --no-install-recommends install netcat idn2 sqlite3 lighttpd php-common php-cgi php-sqlite3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0173179c6da5
Step 27/51 : RUN apt-get install dnsutils -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9aff333b2464
Step 28/51 : RUN apt-get install iputils-ping -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 71854fdd4929
Step 29/51 : RUN apt-get install -y lsof
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a8c2d8bf991b
Step 30/51 : RUN apt-get install sudo -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d83dc0dd04de
Step 31/51 : RUN apt-get install unzip -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8bd66d6f6f59
Step 32/51 : RUN apt-get install -y dns-root-data
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 51db506b63de
Step 33/51 : RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 04823fd87ca9
Step 34/51 : RUN echo "resolvconf resolvconf/linkify-resolvconf boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 31da49abddeb
Step 35/51 : RUN apt install resolvconf -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2d20235c3d99
Step 36/51 : RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3501fe747e84
Step 37/51 : RUN add-apt-repository universe
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 148b8f56762a
Step 38/51 : RUN sed -r -i.orig 's/#?DNSStubListener=yes/DNSStubListener=no/g' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ac2dee94fdfd
Step 39/51 : RUN curl -L https://install.pi-hole.net | bash /dev/stdin --unattended
 ---> Running in c4b0a7bf1522
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     5  100     5    0     0     30      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    30
100  111k  100  111k    0     0   427k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  427k

  [✓] Root user check

        .;;,.
        .ccccc:,.
         :cccclll:.      ..,,
          :ccccclll.   ;ooodc
           'ccll:;ll .oooodc
             .;cll.;;looo:.
                 .. ','.
                .',,,,,,'.
              .',,,,,,,,,,.
            .',,,,,,,,,,,,....
          ....''',,,,,,,'.......
        .........  ....  .........
        ..........      ..........
        ..........      ..........
        .........  ....  .........
          ........,,,,,,,'......
            ....',,,,,,,,,,,,.
               .',,,,,,,,,'.
                .',,,,,,'.
                  ..'''.

  [i] Existing PHP installation detected : PHP version 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  [i] Performing unattended setup, no whiptail dialogs will be displayed
  [✓] Disk space check
  [✓] Update local cache of available packages

  [✗] Checking apt-get for upgraded packages
      Kernel update detected. If the install fails, please reboot and try again
  [i] Installer Dependency checks...
  [✓] Checking for apt-utils
  [✓] Checking for dialog
  [✓] Checking for debconf
  [✓] Checking for dhcpcd5
  [✓] Checking for git
  [✓] Checking for iproute2
  [✓] Checking for whiptail

  [✗] Check for existing repository in /etc/.pihole
  [✓] Clone https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole.git into /etc/.pihole

  [✗] Check for existing repository in /var/www/html/admin
  [✓] Clone https://github.com/pi-hole/AdminLTE.git into /var/www/html/admin

  [i] Main Dependency checks...
  [✓] Checking for cron
  [✓] Checking for curl
  [✓] Checking for dnsutils
  [✓] Checking for iputils-ping
  [✓] Checking for lsof
  [✓] Checking for netcat
  [✓] Checking for psmisc
  [✓] Checking for sudo
  [✓] Checking for unzip
  [✓] Checking for wget
  [✓] Checking for idn2
  [✓] Checking for sqlite3
  [✓] Checking for libcap2-bin
  [✓] Checking for dns-root-data
  [✓] Checking for resolvconf
  [✓] Checking for libcap2
  [✓] Checking for lighttpd
  [✓] Checking for php7.2-common
  [✓] Checking for php7.2-cgi
  [✓] Checking for php7.2-sqlite3

  [✓] Enabling lighttpd service to start on reboot...

  [i] FTL Checks...

  [✓] Detected x86_64 architecture
  [i] Checking for existing FTL binary...
  [✓] Downloading and Installing FTL
  [✓] Creating user 'pihole'
  [✓] Installing scripts from /etc/.pihole

  [i] Installing configs from /etc/.pihole...
  [✓] No dnsmasq.conf found... restoring default dnsmasq.conf...
  [✓] Copying 01-pihole.conf to /etc/dnsmasq.d/01-pihole.conf

  [i] Installing blocking page...
  [✓] Creating directory for blocking page, and copying files
  [✓] Backing up index.lighttpd.html

  [✓] Installing sudoer file

  [✓] Installing latest Cron script

  [✓] Installing latest logrotate script
  [i] Backing up /etc/dnsmasq.conf to /etc/dnsmasq.conf.old
  [i] man not installed
  [i] Testing if systemd-resolved is enabled
  [i] Systemd-resolved does not need to be restarted
  [i] Restarting lighttpd service...The command '/bin/sh -c curl -L https://install.pi-hole.net | bash /dev/stdin --unattended' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am not sure what exactly is causing this issue.

Any ideas or suggestions if someone faced this before?

thanks.

Comment: You must rely on official Docker image, there are multiple complexities involved or need to increase the bounty by 10 times.

Answer (score 5):

There is no service manager (like systemd) in a Docker container so that's probably why it fails.

Why don't you use the official Docker image? https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole

Comment: Because my image is a thoroughly customized due to the project scope and it is impossible to run a separate image...what is doable in this case?

Comment: The https://install.pi-hole.net script is clearny not suited for Docker considering the complexity of the pi-hole/docker-pi-hole repo. I suggest forking the pi-hole/docker-pi-hole repo and adding your customizations on it.